# How to calculate protobuf file size?

Tags: c#, protobuf-net

I'm trying to figure out the final size of a file serialized with protobuf-net, so I'll can choose the best approach.

I made some comparison tests with different proto configurations and a binary serialization, but still I don't understand how "varint to bytes" conversion works.

Classes

```
public class Pt2D
{
    public Pt2D() { }

    public Pt2D(double x, double y)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
    }
    public double X { get; set; }

    public double Y { get; set; }
}

public class Pt3D : Pt2D
{
    public Pt3D() { }

    public Pt3D(double x, double y, double z) : base(x, y)
    {
        Z = z;
    }
    public double Z { get; set; }
}

public class FullPt3D
{
    public FullPt3D() { }

    public FullPt3D(double x, double y, double z)
    {
        X = x;
        Y = y;
        Z = z;
    }

    public double X { get; set; }

    public double Y { get; set; }

    public double Z { get; set; }
}
```

Test case

```
private void ProtoBufferTest()
{            
    var model = RuntimeTypeModel.Default;

    model.Add(typeof(Pt2D), false)
        .Add(1, "X")
        .Add(2, "Y")
        .AddSubType(101, typeof(Pt3D));

    model[typeof(Pt3D)]
        .Add(1, "Z");

    model.Add(typeof(FullPt3D), false)
        .Add(1, "X")
        .Add(2, "Y")
        .Add(3, "Z");

    double x = 5.6050692524784562;
    double y = 0.74161805247031987;
    double z = 8.5883424750474937;

    string filename = "testPt3D.pb";
    using (var file = File.Create(filename))
    {
        Serializer.Serialize(file, new Pt3D(x, y, z));                               
    }
    Console.WriteLine(filename + " length = " + new FileInfo(filename).Length + " bytes") ;

    filename = "testFullPt3D.pb";
    using (var file = File.Create(filename))
    {
        Serializer.Serialize(file, new FullPt3D(x, y, z));                
    }
    Console.WriteLine(filename + " length = " + new FileInfo(filename).Length + " bytes");

    filename = "testBinaryWriter.bin";
    using (var file = File.Create(filename))
    {
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(file))
        {                
            writer.Write(x);
            writer.Write(y);
            writer.Write(z);
        }

    }
    Console.WriteLine(filename + " length = " + new FileInfo(filename).Length + " bytes");


}
```

Test results

1) testPt3D.pb length = 30 bytes

2) testFullPt3D.pb length = 27 bytes

3) testBinaryWriter.bin length = 24 bytes

**Q1)** 24 bytes are used to store the 3 double values and it's ok, but what values are stored in cases 1) and 2) to reach 30 and 27 bytes? (I suppose int values used in model mapping)

**Q2)** I made some tests by changing the SubType mapping for Pt2D but I cannot understand the size changes

```
model.Add(typeof(Pt2D), false)
        .Add(1, "X")
        .Add(2, "Y")
        .AddSubType(3, typeof(Pt3D));
```

Result: testPt3D.pb length = 29 bytes

```
model.Add(typeof(Pt2D), false)
        .Add(1, "X")
        .Add(2, "Y")
        .AddSubType(21, typeof(Pt3D));
```

Result: testPt3D.pb length = 30 bytes

```
model.Add(typeof(Pt2D), false)
        .Add(1, "X")
        .Add(2, "Y")
        .AddSubType(1111, typeof(Pt3D));
```

Result: testPt3D.pb length = 30 bytes

I tried to use [this tool](https://github.com/topas/VarintBitConverter) to better understand, but it gives different bytes conversion results.

Why do I get the same size by using 21, 101 or 1111?

Comment: Still any clues on this? :(

Comment: This functionality is already available in C# API. https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/csharp/interface/google/protobuf/i-message#interface_google_1_1_protobuf_1_1_i_message_1aa3561db050d542706279ffb6ed9315ad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) testPt3D.pb length = 30 bytes

- (subclass comes first) [field 101, string] = 2 bytes, 3 bits for "string", 7 bits for "101"; varint packs in 7 bit units with a continuation bit, so: 2 bytes (total = 2)

  - [data length "9"] = 1 byte (total = 3)
  - [field 1, fixed 64] = 1 byte (total = 4)
  - [payload 1] = 8 bytes (total = 12)
- [field 1, fixed 64] = 1 byte (total = 13)
- [payload 1] = 8 bytes (total = 21)
- [field 2, fixed 64] = 1 byte (total = 22)
- [payload 2] = 8 bytes (total = 30)

2) testFullPt3D.pb length = 27 bytes

- [field 1, fixed 64] = 1 byte (total = 1)
- [payload 1] = 8 bytes (total = 9)
- [field 2, fixed 64] = 1 byte (total = 10)
- [payload 2] = 8 bytes (total = 18)
- [field 3, fixed 64] = 1 byte (total = 19)
- [payload 3] = 8 bytes (total = 27)

There are other options in protobuf when dealing with repeated data - "packed" and "grouped"; they only make sense when discussing *more* data than 3 values, though.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, but the index values that I use to identify fields or subclasses does not affect the size? (see my last question - Why do I get the same size by using 21, 101 or 1111?)

Comment: @ilCosmico the field number is packed in chunks of 7 bits, **but** 3 bits of the first byte are already taken (for the wire-type) - only 4 bits of the first chunk are available for use. So you only get single-byte markers for 1-15 (4 bits); after that, using the next chunk of 7 bits, we get 2-byte markers for 5-11 bits (fields 16-2047). Thus since all of your chosen numbers are in the 16-2047 range, they all take 2 bytes. If you chose "3" it would take 1 byte. If you chose "2500" it will take 3 bytes.

Comment: Last doubt, the [data length "9"] = 1 byte what is exactly?

Comment: @ilCosmico it is encoding the length of the data that follows, which is 9 bytes; to do so it encodes `9` using "varint" encoding, which takes one byte (the value 0x09)